# How to solve a false NullPointerException in Maven project with a jUnit test?

Tags: java, maven, junit

I made a small application with a student...

I got a Student.java class with studentId(integer), firstName(string) and lastName(string), with geters and setters and constructor

```
public Student(Integer studentId, String firstName, String lastName) {
    this();
    this.studentId = studentId;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

in App.java (Maven generated this class for me), I got this code:

```
@PersistenceContext
static
EntityManager em;

public static Boolean addStudent(Student s) {
try{
    em.persist(s);
    em.flush();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

    return true;
}
```

Then i made a database with the name testStudent

in my pom.xml file i added this line:

```
 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <server>localhost</server>
    <database>testStudent</database>
    <port>8080</port>
 </properties>
```

I hope that is how you add a DB to the maven project...?

Then I made a jUnit test in an another package:

AppT.java, and there I got this test:

```
@Test
public void testAddStudent(){
    Student s = new Student(4,"aaa","bbb");
    Boolean b = App.addStudent(s);

    assert(b);
}
```

Once I run the test, there is a java.lang.NullPointerException on the line in App.java, where i persist the new student...

```
em.persist(s); // here is the exception
em.flush();
```

Now i don't understand, how is that possible, bc in my test, i create a new Student, with his own attributes....and he should not be null

Can someone explain it to me? Thx
Btw. I am using Arquillian too....if that helps...

Answer (score -1):

I guess in your scenario Student is not null, but the instance of EntityManager em could be null. Please check how its been initialized for test environment

Comment: I just have @PersistenceContext static EntityManager em; in my App.java class....nothing else

Comment: This would make a better comment than an answer IMO. It just suggests what _could_ be the problem, but still leaves the problem open and unsolved.

Comment: That is to autowire the dependency. But I guess some mock instance of it has to be initialized some where. Please ensure its initialized by the test framework you are using. May be @Before or something similar location

Comment: should i add that in the AppT.java where the tests are, or in the App.java where the actual function is?

Comment: It should be in AppT.java itself for a test scenario, but not sure how your mocking framework injects it for autowired annotation

Comment: do u need more of my code to see? Btw i need to go on a break now, i ll be back soon

Comment: I added  @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager em; to the AppT.java class to create an entity manager....but i am still confused how should i use it?